# the performance of k-means for clustering is very bad, how to improve it?

Tags: python, pyspark, k-means

I am working on clustering by k-means with pyspark.ml. The data has about 5 million rows and 100 features, which are all categorical. I use one-hot encoding to transform them.

I just used the code in the following example:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/ml/kmeans_example.py

But, the performance of k-means is very bad. The average Silhouette with squared euclidean distance is about

```
  0.15
```

I have tried to change the k value (from 2 to 3000) and random seed between 1 and 1 million. But, the performance is similar.

From this average Silhouette value, may I have the conclusion that the data cannot be partitioned into different clusters well ?

Or, there may be outliers that cause the problem and I need to drop some features ? If yes, how to determine which ones should be dropped or regulated?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any other distance metrics such as Manhattan, Pearson, or Spearman? It highly depends on the dataset and on the objective, but its worth a try since it can affect clustering performance.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see the options for distances in pyspark API docs. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans